# Load more data to html template on fake page scroll, performance issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

I have a javascript object contains 3000 records of addresses. If i load all the addresses in tiles in a container, it's very slow. What i want is :
 - I want to load 15-18 address tiles on load
 - setting the container height dynamically calculating from tile height so that scroll will be created on container load based on number of records. ex: tile height: 80px, and total address records: 3000, so the container height = 3000*80
 - i want to append few tiles from javascript object to html template on page scroll

But when scroll very first, my approach is not working. i can see blank space on bottom. So is there anything that i can follow to achieve to load more addresses on fast scroll also.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could put some code for us to see, either here or link to a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I have modified my question with sample code, code is just to give an idea.. i have not tested the sample code. Thanks

Comment: thanks for your help but it won't for a fake scroll. What i need is to fix the container height on load based on the total number of address so that user will think like all are loaded but on scroll i want to load few more.. 
I have modified something to set initial height and setting fake scroll..
Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxc8eba/2/

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle using fake scroll: [https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxc8eba/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxc8eba/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lxc8eba/1/)

It uses standard JavaScript and jQuery to load an infinite amount of results based upon scroll position.

```js
//View contains references and data concerning the screen, scroll, etc...
var view = {};
var tileSize = 72;
//List of results
var results = [];
//Function to get results.
//If you load all on load, ignor this
function getResults(min, max) {
 //Here should be an AJAX call to the server
 //I'll just generate some dummies since i don't have access to a server
 var returner = []
 for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {
  returner.push({
   "LastName" : ["Ken", "Zarah", "Thrawn", "Oakenshield"][Math.round(Math.random() * 3)],
   "EmailAddress" : "alteam06@scanapp.local",
   "Id" : Math.round(Math.random() * 1000),
   "FirstName" : ["Sai", "Zayda", "Han", "Lurtz"][Math.round(Math.random() * 3)],
   "Drawn" : false
  })
 }
 //Return results
 return returner
}
//Function to display new tiles
function drawTiles() {
 //We want to manipulate the actual DOM tree as little as possible to save calculations.
 //Therefore we will compile our results into one string and then append them all at once.
 var html = '';
 //Only get results that hasn't yet been drawn
 results.filter(function (result) {
  return result.Drawn == false;
 }).forEach(function (el) {
  html += '<div style="height:' + tileSize + 'px; float:left; margin: 2em;">';
  html += '<p>' + el.FirstName + ' ' + el.LastName + '</p>';
  html += '<p>' + el.EmailAddress + '</p>';
  html += '<p>' + el.Id + '</p>';
  html += '</div>';
  el.drawn = true;
 });
 document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += html;
}
//Function handle to request and draw a bundle
function getBundle() {
 //Change the min, max here if you plan to send these parameters with AJAX
 results = results.concat(getResults(0, 10));
 drawTiles();
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 //Listen for scroll events
 jQuery(document).on("scroll", function (evt) {
  //If we are low enough in the scroll
  if (window.scrollY > jQuery("#results").height() - window.innerHeight - (2 * tileSize)) {
   getBundle();
  }
 })
 //Run initial build
 getBundle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The container for the tiles -->
<div id="results" style="float:left">

</div>
```